# rust-lld is missing, how do I install it?

Tags: rust

When I try compiling for webasm, I get an error “rust-lld not found”. What should I do?

I have been following the instructions in the rust webasm book with a dummy program,  and everything worked up till the initial compile,  which failed with this error which apparently means that some linker has not been installed.

My context is Ubuntu on an ARM 64 bit box.

Comment: It might be good if you share the link of the tutorial you are following. It might be mentioned somewhere how to find your `rust-lld`.

Comment: It was a Mozilla Development  Network  tutorial, I think https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Rust_to_wasm

Answer (score 6):

`rust-lld` is in a non `$PATH`-path which means you have to use either the full path or add the path to your `$PATH` environment variable.

In my case it can be found in `~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rust-lld`

Of course the path may vary by architecture and version.